# How do I edit the source code of jar in android studio?

Tags: android, android-studio

I have added Watchdog `jar` as a library to the project. I am able to see the code but unable to modify it. How can I edit the `jar` source code?

Files in the code coming with a lock symbol .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The jar that you added is already packaged, meaning you can't edit it anymore. What you can do, is fork the watchdog library, make your changes to that version, and then build the library and add the newly generated jar to your project.

**To do this**, first download the sourcecode on github, with the "Clone or download" button. Afterwards, extract the zip file, and open the project in android studio.

Now you can make your changes to the source code. After you are done, go back to your main project, and right click it in the project view. Go to "Open Module Settings", and click on the plus sign in the top left. Then select "Import Gradle Project", and choose the directory, of the downloaded and modified watchdog version. Additionally remove the previously added jar from the project, and you should now have the modified version of watchdog, imported into your project.

Comment: what is forking ?i don,t know much about github..this is the jar i added link is here..https://github.com/SalomonBrys/ANR-WatchDog#watchdog-thread

Comment: See my updated answer, i provided an explanation on how to Download , Modify and Import the modified library.

Comment: may errors are coming after opening the project (i mean extracted zip)in studio.. i think may be problem with library

Comment: What kind of errors? It's a gradle project, so android studio should be able to import it. Alternatively, if you can't get the library importing to work, you could just copy the 2 java source files in the library, into your project. (Though actually keeping it in a separet project is recommended)

Comment: Erro as:Error:(44, 0) No such property: ossrhUsername for class: org.gradle.api.publication.maven.internal.deployer.DefaultGroovyMavenDeployer
<a href="openFile:/home/manvish/Downloads/ANR-WatchDog-master/anr-watchdog/build.gradle">Open File</a>

Comment: The uploadArchives method is only used to deploy to the maven repository. For your local build you can remove the method in order to have the library build locally.

Comment: As i said, if importing the project as a module doesn't work for you, just copy the 2 .java source files from the "ANR-WatchDog-master\anr-watchdog\src\main\java\com\github\anrwatchdog" directory to your project, and then modify them.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it.

**But** There is a [Transform API](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/transform-api) in android gradle plugin which allow you to manipulate your source code.

For example you can use [javassist](https://github.com/jboss-javassist/javassist) inside your transform task and change your jar file.

This solution is a little hard, an easy alternative is to fork Watchdog library and make a new modified jar file